# SQL Get monthly values for a yearly subscription

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with orders like this:

```
date, domain, total
2022-01-07, test.com, 120
```

The business requirement is that these are yearly subscriptions, and I need to look at how much they will theoretically bring in every month. So the output should be the following:

```
date, domain, total
2022-01-07, test.com, 10
2022-02-07, test.com, 10
2022-03-07, test.com, 10
2022-04-07, test.com, 10
2022-05-07, test.com, 10
2022-06-07, test.com, 10
2022-07-07, test.com, 10
2022-08-07, test.com, 10
2022-09-07, test.com, 10
2022-10-07, test.com, 10
2022-11-07, test.com, 10
2022-12-07, test.com, 10
```

Essentially, each order should be split into 12 lines, with the starting date being the date of the order and the last date being date + 12 month. Also, the amount has to be divided by 12 for each month.

I am using postgreSQL.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried?

Comment: Also, I believe your expected result should have number 10 in result ?

Comment: thanks, I've fixed it. I was looking at similar questions, but they have hardcoded values for dates which is not useful to me. I was thinking of using some sort of range, but I am not that versed in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.date + (m.n * interval '1 month'), domain, total / 12
from t
cross join generate_series(0, 11) m (n)
```

Result:

```
 ?column?             domain    ?column? 
 -------------------- --------- -------- 
 2022-01-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-02-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-03-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-04-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-05-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-06-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-07-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-08-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-09-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-10-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-11-07 00:00:00  test.com  10       
 2022-12-07 00:00:00  test.com  10
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3412652bc80fa90f82bc5f7a4e64d55b).

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=643b4940ff1337ce9c35a81eae8dbb20)

You can use `generate_series()` for that:

```
SELECT 
    gs::date as my_new_date,
    domain,
    total / 12 as my_new_total
FROM mytable,
    generate_series(mydate, mydate + interval '11 months', interval '1 month') gs
```

Parameters for `generate_series()`:

1. The date of your record (start)
2. The date of your record + 12 months (end)
3. Interval length (1 month)

---

Note:

1. `date` is not a good name of a column. First, it is a reserved keyword of Postgres; Second because it does not exactly describe what date is meant.
2. This approach does not work correctly when it comes to the end of the month. Think about January 31st. What is the next month? February 31st does not even exist. Here you'll need to specify your requirements better.

Comment: "*Think about January 31st.*" - Postgres can handle that ;) `date '2022-01-31' + interval '1 month'` returns 2022-02-28

Comment: Thanks, everyday I learn something new

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name was not aware of it! Thanks.